# Listado de candidatos incompleto

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un código en php que muestra una lista de candidatos nominados a una posición, tengo ademas dos listas con los candidatos según la posición la cual subo a la base de datos, una de las listas contiene 589 candidatos y la otra lista contiene 581 candidatos.

Cuando las personas entran al sistema para ejercer la votación solo pueden ver o aparecen en el listado de candidatos 549 cuando se sube la lista de 581 y cuando de sube la lista de 589 solo se pueden ver 494, en la base de datos aparecen todos, pero los usuarios no pueden ver todos los candidatos.

¿Como puedo hacer o que esta pasando que mi lista no esta siendo mostrada completamente?

```
<!-- Voting Ballot Donde se ven los candidatos y puedes votar-->
<form method="POST" id="ballotForm" action="submit_ballot.php">
    <?php
        include 'includes/slugify.php';
        
        $candidate = '';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY priority ASC";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $sql = "Select C.id, C.credentials, C.firstname, C.lastname from candidates C LEFT JOIN positions P ON P.priority =                                                   C.position_id GROUP BY C.credentials ORDER by C.credentials ASC";
            $cquery = $conn->query($sql);
            while($crow = $cquery->fetch_assoc()){
                $slug = slugify($row['description']);
                $checked = '';
                if(isset($_SESSION['post'][$slug])){
                    $value = $_SESSION['post'][$slug];

                    if(is_array($value)){
                        foreach($value as $val){
                            if($val == $crow['id']){
                                $checked = 'checked';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if($value == $crow['id']){
                            $checked = 'checked';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $input = ($row['max_vote'] > 1) ? 
                '<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red '.$slug.'" name="'.$slug."[]".'" value="'.$crow['id'].'" '.$checked.'>' : 
                '<input type="radio" class="flat-red '.$slug.'" name="'.slugify($row['description']).'" value="'.$crow['id'].'"                                                         '.$checked.'>';
                
                $candidate .= '
                    <li>
                        '.$input.'
            <i class="fa fa
            ="100px" class="clist"><span class="cname clist">'.$crow['credentials'].' '.$crow['firstname'].' '.$crow['lastname'].'</span>
                    </li>
                ';
            }
            
            $instruct = ($row['max_vote'] > 1) ? 'You may select up to '.$row['max_vote'].' candidates' : 'Selecciona un candidato';
            
            echo '
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-14">
                        <div class="box box-solid" id="'.$row['id'].'">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                    <br><br>
                                <h3 class="box-title"><b>'.$row['description'].'</b></h3>
                            <div class="box-body">
                            <p>'.$instruct.'
                                    <span class="pull-right">
                                        <button onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Actualizar Página</button>
                                    </span>
                                    <th class="hidden"></th>
                                </p>
                                <div id="candidate_list">
                                    <ul>
                                        '.$candidate.'
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';

            $candidate = '';
        }   

    ?>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="vote"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Someter</button>
    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- End Voting Ballot -->
```

Comment: ¿Todos tienen un valor del campo `candidates.credentials` diferente?. Agrega un `COUNT(*)` al `SELECT` para saber qué candidatos repiten el valor de `credentials` y, por lo tanto, quedan ocultos bajo un mismo registro. También puedes agregar un `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` al final de la consulta para que te muestre solo los que compartan dicho campo. Ese el motivo más probable por el que aparentemente no aparecen todos los candidatos en el listado.

Comment: Sí, todos tienen un valor diferente en credentials, que es el numero de identificación (5 dígitos) de esos candidatos, pero acabo de verificar y no se repiten.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer una de las dos consultas que te he propuesto? Ya que el `LEFT JOIN` no debería eliminar registros de la tabla `candidates`, entonces la agrupación es lo único que tiene sentido que reduzca el número de candidatos mostrados. Por cierto, ¿para qué haces el primer `SELECT`? ¿Imagino que solo tienes una prioridad?

Comment: Fue un amigo que realizó esa parte del código. Intenté hacer la consulta, pero no se donde ubicar correctamente el ```COUNT(*)``` o el ```HAVING COUNT(*) > 1```, y me da error en el sql de phpmyadmin

Comment: El primero se coloca como un campo más del `SELECT` y el segundo se coloca justo al final de la consulta, antes del `ORDER BY`. Por ejemplo: `Select C.id, C.credentials, C.firstname, C.lastname from candidates C LEFT JOIN positions P ON P.priority = C.position_id GROUP BY C.credentials HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER by C.credentials ASC`. Por cierto, ese `SELECT` exterior hará que se repita la consulta SQL tantas veces como registros tenga la tabla `positions`.

Comment: Por último, ¿cómo cuentas el número de candidatos que se muestran en la página?

Comment: Realicé el de ```HAVING COUNT(*) > 1``` y este fue el resultado "MySQL returned an empty result set". Por lo menos en ```positions``` solo hay 1 row ya que la votación es un puesto a la vez.

Comment: No los cuento en realidad solo me dejo llevar por el numero de ```credentials``` ya que corre desde el 00001 al 00589

Comment: Bien, que no entregue ningún resultado indica que es cierto, no se repite ningún valor. ¿Estás seguro que no se salta ningún número en la secuencia? ¿Cuantos registros dice phpmyadmin que hay en la tabla? Puedo hacerte un pequeño código JavaScript para que cuente el número de elementos que muestras por pantalla, para ver si coinciden.

Comment: Dice que hay 589 en la tabla de phpmyadmin

Comment: Para ver el número de registros mostrados en pantalla usa, por ejemplo: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div.row > div.col-xs-14 > div.box-solid').length);`

Comment: Donde lo debo colocar?

Comment: Aparte de todo lo comentado con @OscarGarcia, considera armar una sola consulta. En el código se observa que ejecutas una primera consulta y luego, dentro de la lectura de los resultados de esa primera consulta ejecutas `N` consultas en bucle, donde `N` será el total de filas de la 1ª consulta. Así tu código no está optimizado, cada llamada a `query()` tiene un costo, si ejecutas una sola consulta y trabajas sobre ese único resultado es mucho mejor.

Comment: Debes ejecutarlo en la consola de depuración de Javascript. En la mayoría de navegadores accedes a ella pulsando F12.

Comment: Ok, salió un 1 y luego undefined

Comment: Solo encontró una coincidencia porque vi mal en anidado del código, el código correcto para contar los registros debería ser `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#candidate_list > ul > li').length);`.

Comment: Le borre los signos entre ```#candidate_list ul li``` y mostró 589 en la consola ```console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#candidate_list  ul  li').length);```

Comment: Pues solucionado, están todos los registros, no falta ninguno.

Comment: El problema esta en que no todos se ven todos en la lista del usuario que va a votar

Comment: no se si son ideas mias pero en tu codigo el query tiene como 40 espacios demas ....

Comment: ¿Qué lista debe ver? Según el código de la consulta SQL muestra todos los requisitos de la tabla.

Comment: el otro problema que veo es que si tu estructura de tu base de datos o un ejemplo mínimo reproducible poco puedo hacer para ayudarte...

Comment: @OscarGarcia se supone que se vea la lista de candidatos completa los 589 y solo se ven 494. Puedes verlo en [enlace](https://eleccionesenlinea.com/idpmi) user y pass 33238